# How to expand all Panels in Antd Collapse without specifying every single tab key as activeKey

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to keep all the Panels open when the page loads for the first time. 
Using Antd Collapse and there is already an option to add the key of the panel as an array of string , so that the mentioned panels will be open by default.
I am finding it difficult to obtain this key. Is there any other way to make all the panels open on first load (like example use any props in the collapse to keep it open)? I have written the toggle panel on click. That works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Specify all active keys in `defaultActiveKey` list

```
<Collapse defaultActiveKey={['1', '2']}>
    <Collapse.Panel header="Group name" key="1">
        ...
    </Collapse.Panel>
    <Collapse.Panel header="Group name" key="2">
        ...
    </Collapse.Panel>
</Collapse>
```

Or if you want to use dynamic keys use this way

```
const panels = [{name: '1'}, {name: '2'}]
<Collapse activeKey={panels.map(panel => panel.name)}>
    {
        panels.map(panel => (
            <Collapse.Panel header={panel.name} key={panel.name}>
                ...
            </Collapse.Panel>
        ));
    }
</Collapse>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the collapse independently with state, for example:

```js
const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState([panels[0]?.header]);
        
<Collapse activeKey={activeKey} onChange={(e) => setActiveKey(e)}>
  <CollapseHeader>
    <Icon icon="expand_all" onClick={() => setActiveKey(panels.map((panel) => panel.header))} />
    <Icon icon="collapse_all" onClick={() => setActiveKey([])} />
    {panels.map((panel) => <Panel header={panel.header} key={panel.header}>...</Panel>)}
</Collapse>
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of keys are you trying to use?  Are they generated in some way or other? Or can you just use a simple numeric index?

Let's say you have 5 panels, and the id's would be 0-4, a simple map alone would generate the array of indices:

```
const arrayOfKeys = panels.map((panel, index) => index);
```

I suppose the next alternative is to try and access the properties of the panel itself and run a handler on them:

```
 const arrayOfKeys = panels.map((panel) => panel.props.someFunc());
```

Hopefully I am not over simplifying what you have described, but perhaps you can share some code.

Hope this helps.